# Create a queue system

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a queue system that works in this way:

- A user fills in a form where they will have to enter some data.
- Click on Send and these data will be saved in a sql table.
- Going to the index.php page will see a box containing a text like this: There are 4 requests in front of you, please wait a few minutes.

I have already tried to do such a thing, but going to create new requests the number "4" of the message grows.
This is because I created a query that counts all the results on the table.

`$query = $mysql->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS q FROM application_approve");`

While I want it to count only the results above the request that sent the user.

```
id  name            text        text2
1   First request   dassasad    dsadasas
2   Second request  dassasad    dsadasas
3   Third request   dsadasdsas  dsadasad
```

In the example above I would like to count only how many lines there are above the "Second Request": in this case 1.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the schema of your table(s). Also, which field or fields are used to select the user's info, and which field determines the ordering of the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table has a PK (`id`) and references a `user_id` to identify which request belongs to which user and assuming there can only be a single request in the queue per user then your query would look something like the following.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS q FROM application_approve
    WHERE id < (
        SELECT id FROM application_approve
        WHERE user_id = ?
    )
```

This also assumes the PK `id` is an auto-incrementing key.

Given the `user_id` this query would return the number of rows above the given user's row (*assuming they have one*). Or, in other words, all ids less than the id of the given user.

For simplicity, let's assume this schema only has 2 columns (`id` and `user_id`):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM application_approve;
+------+---------+
| id   | user_id |
+------+---------+
|    1 |       1 |
|    2 |       2 |
|    3 |       3 |
+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in the given table, there are 3 users, each with 1 entry in the queue.

If we wanted to find which position user 2 is in the query would give us the following result:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(id) AS q FROM application_approve WHERE id < (SELECT id FROM application_approve WHERE user_id = 2);
+---+
| q |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```